# Custom Segue push weird behavior

Tags: iphone, sdk, uigesturerecognizer, uistoryboard

I am trying a simple project (storyboard) where the user swipes from right to left to get to the next view and so on and to go back the user swipes from left to right.
I want to achieve the transition to follow the swipe (L-->R or R-->L).

I have found this:

```
-(void)perform {

    UIViewController *sourceViewController = (UIViewController*)[self sourceViewController];
    UIViewController *destinationController = (UIViewController*)[self destinationViewController];

    CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.duration = .25;
    transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    transition.type = kCATransitionPush; //kCATransitionMoveIn; //, kCATransitionPush, kCATransitionReveal, kCATransitionFade
    transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft; //kCATransitionFromLeft, kCATransitionFromRight, kCATransitionFromTop, kCATransitionFromBottom



    [sourceViewController.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition
                                                                forKey:kCATransition];

    [sourceViewController.navigationController pushViewController:destinationController animated:NO];

}
```

but this doesn't seem to be doing what is supposed to do.

**EXPLAIN:**

when i m in landscape (my project only works in landscape) and home button is on the left, the animation comes from the TOP!!!
When I m in landscape and home button is on the right the animation comes from the BOTTOM!!!

Although I have specified it to be from the left.
The other thing is that it changes direction when i use diferent landscapes (homebutton on the left or right).

Any ideas why is this happening???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok this is how I did it, although VERY un-orthodox.

Im checking the orientation of the iPad and then instead of going left or right im actually going top/ bottom...
ok this is how I did it, although VERY un-orthodox.

Im checking the orientation of the iPad and then instead of going left or right im actually going top/ bottom...

```
if([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
{
      //Landscape Left

//.......
       transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromTop;

}
else if([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
{
      //Landscape Right

//......
       transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromBottom;

}
```

Comment: I saw that you edited it 1 min ago and I have deleted my comment. But to be honest, I don't think the answer was a accident, as that was 26 mins ago and hasn't anything to do with your current answer content...

Comment: it was intended to be a comment and not an answer but i was also in the middle of searching/ testing / upset with Apple etc. anyway sorry if it caused you trouble.. and thanks for your help...

Answer (score 0):

Are your views in a nav controller?
Have you tried simply using the segue with "push" style?

In your swipe gesture recognizer, just call:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"NextScreenIdentifier" sender:sender];
```

and you should get the correct behavior (left->right / right->left transition).

Comment: yes im with nav control. I dont declare my swipe gesture recognizer anywhere. it s all in IB and storyboard

Comment: So, just control-drag from your swipe-gesture-recognizer to the destination view, and pick "push".  Do same each of your recognizers (left and right).  Since you're transitioning left/right it should "just work".

Comment: i have "push" to move forward. BUT is is highly - unintuitive to swipe from R-->L and the view to appear from L-->R... cause this is what you get if you go with push.